# apt-get not installing package but no error?

Tags: apt

Not necessarily asking for a solution but just the meaning of what I'm dealing with:

```
admin@hostname:/etc/apache2/mods-available$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

admin@hostname:/etc/apache2/mods-available$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-mono

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libapache2-mod-mono' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 191 not upgraded.
```

If the package isn't being installed why am I not receiving an error? If I do an apt-cache search the package name shows up and the apt logs don't even mention me trying to install this package.

For more background I'm running debian 8.1 (Jessie) on AWS. I was following these instructions: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libjpeg62-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Without an error I'm not really sure what to do. I've never seen apt-get do this before. Help?

**EDIT:**

Here's the policy information:

```
admin@hostname:~$ apt-cache policy

Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy-libjpeg62-compat/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=XamarinLibJpeg62Compat,a=stable-libjpeg62-compat,n=wheezy-libjpeg62-compat,l=Xamarin-Stable-libjpeg62-compat,c=main
     origin download.mono-project.com
 500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy-apache24-compat/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=XamarinApache24Compat,a=stable-apache24-compat,n=wheezy-apache24-compat,l=Xamarin-Stable-apache24-compat,c=main
     origin download.mono-project.com
 500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Xamarin,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Xamarin-Stable,c=main
     origin download.mono-project.com
 500 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin cloudfront.debian.net
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://cloudfront.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.2,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin cloudfront.debian.net
Pinned packages:

admin@hostname:~$ apt-cache policy libapache2-mod-mono

libapache2-mod-mono:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.12-0xamarin2+compat1
  Version table:
     3.12-0xamarin2+compat1 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy-apache24-compat/main amd64 Packages
     3.12-0xamarin2 0
        500 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Post the output of `apt-cache policy libapache2-mod-mono` in your question, not the comments. Also the output of `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Done

Comment: Based on the information given, I'm not sure what is going on either. One comment: if you are using third-party sources, pin them to something lower than 100, I usually use 50. That way you don't have to worry about upgrading to third party packages accidentally. If you want to talk, come to the main chat room. I can try to take a closer look. I'm not there all the time, but if you ping me, I'll see it eventually. BTW, you also probably don't want to be using third-party wheezy repositories on a jessie system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging and dmesg was reporting some segfaults coming from aptitude.

```
[ 7384.810518] apt-get[6440]: segfault at 7f5adb08a648 ip 00007f5adb08a648 sp 00007ffdf4b9d618 error 15
[ 7433.569688] apt-get[6450]: segfault at 7f153041d648 ip 00007f153041d648 sp 00007ffc6bfb29d8 error 15
[ 7624.614647] apt-get[6493]: segfault at 7fae19437318 ip 00007fae19437318 sp 00007ffebd660c78 error 15
[ 7647.248347] apt-get[6505]: segfault at 7fcbdedc2318 ip 00007fcbdedc2318 sp 00007ffef87ad688 error 15
[ 7726.721028] apt-get[6539]: segfault at 7f0d0bc0b848 ip 00007f0d0bc0b848 sp 00007ffdb6f55588 error 15
[ 7872.903745] apt-get[6547]: segfault at 7f69c0caf848 ip 00007f69c0caf848 sp 00007ffcc83296c8 error 15
[ 8009.062830] apt-get[6561]: segfault at 7fe658208848 ip 00007fe658208848 sp 00007ffeeac5e398 error 15
[ 8033.035303] apt-get[6567]: segfault at 7ff32b0fa848 ip 00007ff32b0fa848 sp 00007ffd55d04cd8 error 15
[12626.030754] apt-get[6679]: segfault at 7faa21fa5848 ip 00007faa21fa5848 sp 00007fffb0badc28 error 15
```

Faheem asked what happens if I try to install a package I've already installed so I tried `mono-devel`. I had already installed this package but I did so prior to adding some of the package sources I mentioned above.

Anyway after mono-devel finished installing again I tried installing `libapache2-mod-mono` again and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

> apt-get update; apt-get purge libapache2-mod-mono; apt-get -f install; apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono

If that won't help then please read here:

[How to run mod_mono on Debian Jessie (package libapache2-mod-mono missing)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197459/how-to-run-mod-mono-on-debian-jessie-package-libapache2-mod-mono-missing)

Comment: Can you give some background on what this is doing?

Comment: `apt-get update` makes sure your repo metadata is current vis-a-vis package availability and versions.  `apt-get purge $PACKAGE` removes any cached copy of the package from your local system.  `apt-get -f install` will clean up any incomplete or broken install or uninstall processes.  After all this, a fresh try at installing the package is attempted.

Comment: These commands had no affect. apt-get doesn't do anything it just kicks me back to the command line after the usual output. :(

Comment: So the problem is much deeper, has to do with Jessie and you should read up the other thread about same thing that i linked. It's all explained in depth in there.