# Unmet dependencies when using target release

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, package-management, dependencies

I'm running Debian Jessie (stable) and I followed [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253866/48590) to install a single package from stretch (testing).

But I get an "unmet dependencies" error. How can I fix the issue and install the testing version of that package?

```
$ sudo apt-get -t stretch install libboost-all-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: gnome-settings-daemon (< 3.19.92) but 3.14.2-3 is to be installed
                             Breaks: mutter (< 3.19.92) but 3.14.4-1~deb8u1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (< 1.7.90) but 1.4.4-2.1+deb8u1 is to be installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad (< 1.7.1) but 1.4.4-2.1+deb8u1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: read this answer on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

Comment: Did not make a diffference - there are no kept back dependencies as far as I can see. Also if I run `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` (without the target version), everything works fine.

Comment: You will break your system , see the dependencies of [gnome-settings-daemon](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome-settings-daemon)

Comment: @GAD3R But I'm trying to install a recent version of boost, which has absolutely nothing to do with gnome... And I'm happy with the version of gnome that I have