# Installing a package from Debian unstable into testing without setting priorities

Tags: debian, apt

To install a package from Debian Unstable into my Testing release I've followed a solution found at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253866/261200).

First, I added unstable as repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list`:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list
deb http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

Second, I set priorities for testing:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/default-release
APT::Default-Release "testing";
```

After executing `apt update update` I searched for a package `nautilus-actions` which should be [available for `Sid`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nautilus-actions). However, running `apt search nautilus-actions` give no result. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can’t install the package in either testing or unstable is that it was [removed in September 2017](https://bugs.debian.org/876271) because it’s obsolete. It isn’t available in any release of Debian after that. It was supposed to be replaced by [`filemanager-actions`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/filemanager-actions), which was [briefly available in Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/filemanager-actions) (but never released); the closest currently-available replacement is [actions-for-nautilus](https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus) which [will hopefully be available in Debian soon](https://bugs.debian.org/1016022).

When you looked for it, it was still listed as available in debports for arm64 but that was only because it hadn’t been cleaned up there; it wasn’t actually downloadable from debports (following the links available at the time led to a 404 error).

Answer (score 0):

As your [link](https://packages.debian.org/sid/nautilus-actions) says it's a [debports](https://www.ports.debian.org/) package, so it is only available on **arm64** architecture.
Are you sure you're using an arm64 based machine?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I don't run that kind of machine.

Comment: No, it’s not “only available on arm64”. The debports listing is a leftover and doesn’t point to an available file. It’s an obsolete package which has been removed.