# How to upgrade GRUB v1 to GRUB v2 without installing a Beta version?

Tags: debian, grub2, grub

My Linux Debian v9.11.0 (Stretch) currently has `GRUB1` installed.

```
root@Debian:~# grub-install -v
grub-install (GNU GRUB 0.97)
```

My other Ubuntu Linux has `GRUB2` installed:

```
root@Ubuntu:~# grub-install -V
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02+dfsg1-20
```

I want to install `GRUB2`, but if I try to install it on the Debian with `apt-get install grub2`, a beta version of `GRUB2` is installed !!!

```
root@Debian:~# grub-install -V
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2
```

I do not want this beta version - I want a stable version of `GRUB2` like the one that Ubuntu has installed.

When searching for available `GRUB2` packages from the Debian, I get only `beta` packages listed:

```
root@Debian:~# apt search GRUB2
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
grub-imageboot/oldstable 0.6 all
  boot iso, harddisk and floppy images with grub2 and syslinux memdisk

grub2/oldstable,now 2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2 amd64 [residual-config]
  GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (dummy package)

grub2-common/oldstable 2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2 amd64
  GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)

grub2-splashimages/oldstable 1.0.1+nmu1 all
  a collection of great GRUB2 splashimages

live-wrapper/oldstable 0.6+nmu1 all
  Wrapper for vmdebootstrap for creating live images

live-wrapper-doc/oldstable 0.6+nmu1 all
  Wrapper for vmdebootstrap for creating live images (Documentation)

vmdebootstrap/oldstable 1.7-1 amd64
  Bootstrap Debian into a (virtual machine) disk image
```

How to install a **non-beta** version of `GRUB2` on the Debian ?

Comment: It's fine to use the beta version.  It has a lot of fixes that the original 2.00 does not, and was the best available version at the time of release.  Using the 2.00 stable version would have been a disservice to users.  You could also just upgrade to `buster`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the current version from [buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/grub2) which is the same version as from your Ubuntu.

As described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253866/332764), you could add the buster main repository to your apt sources and set the default release to "stretch" to give packages from stretch a higher priority. You can then install newer 
packages from buster manually with `sudo apt -t buster install nameofpackage`.

Instructions:

1. Create file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/buster.list` containing the buster main repository

   ```
   deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
   ```
2. Create file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/default-release` with this content

   ```
   APT::Default-Release "stretch";
   ```

   Choose either "stretch" or "oldstable" as default release name.
3. Run

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

   to update your package indexes.

   If you now run `apt policy grub2` the output should look similar to this:

   ```
   apt policy grub2
   grub2:
     Installed: (none)
     Candidate: 2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2
     Version table:
        2.02+dfsg1-20 500
           500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2 990
           990 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
   ```

   As you can see the version from the buster repository has a lower priority of 500.
4. Install or upgrade `grub2` with

   ```
   sudo apt -t buster install grub2
   ```

Comment: That's a functional workaround, but why does the Debian "Stretch" repository contain **only 
 beta** versions of `GRUB2` in the first place ?   After all, GRUB v2.00 was released 5 years BEFORE Debian "Stretch" was released, see here:  https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/   Is this a bug in this distro ?