# Why is Debian "Stretch" force feeding me with unstable (beta) GRUB package?

Tags: debian, grub2, grub, repository

When searching for available `GRUB2` packages for the Debian v9.11.0 "Stretch", I get only `beta` packages listed:

```
root@Debian:~# apt search GRUB2
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
grub-imageboot/oldstable 0.6 all
  boot iso, harddisk and floppy images with grub2 and syslinux memdisk

grub2/oldstable,now 2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2 amd64 [residual-config]
  GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (dummy package)

grub2-common/oldstable 2.02~beta3-5+deb9u2 amd64
  GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)

grub2-splashimages/oldstable 1.0.1+nmu1 all
  a collection of great GRUB2 splashimages

live-wrapper/oldstable 0.6+nmu1 all
  Wrapper for vmdebootstrap for creating live images

live-wrapper-doc/oldstable 0.6+nmu1 all
  Wrapper for vmdebootstrap for creating live images (Documentation)

vmdebootstrap/oldstable 1.7-1 amd64
  Bootstrap Debian into a (virtual machine) disk image
```

As you can see, this search returns only **beta** packages.
I had to jump through hoops to install a stable `GRUB2` package, see: 
[How to upgrade GRUB v1 to GRUB v2 without installing a Beta version?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560543/how-to-upgrade-grub-v1-to-grub-v2-without-installing-a-beta-version)

QUESTION: Why does the Debian "Stretch" repository contain **only beta** versions of the `GRUB2` in the first place ?
After all, the stable `GRUB` v2.00 was released 5 years BEFORE Debian "Stretch" was released, see here:
[ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub)

Is this a bug in this distro's repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those were the best available versions when Debian 9 was released.

Looking at [the changelog leading up to version 2.02~beta3-5deb9u2](https://tracker.debian.org/media/packages/g/grub2/changelog-2.02beta3-5deb9u2) provides some explanation:

- 2.00 was indeed released in 2012, and uploaded to Debian experimental; it was uploaded to unstable (targeting the next stable release) in May 2013, after 14 revisions in Debian (and with a number of fixes from Ubuntu);
- many uploads of 2.00 with additional fixes followed, suggesting that 2.00 suffered from a number of bugs;
- in December 2013, a snapshot of the GRUB repository was packaged, with many more fixes, confirming the above;
- subsequent beta releases were packaged, again in experimental first, fixed, and eventually released in Debian 9, with [a large number of patches on top of the official “beta” release](https://sources.debian.org/src/grub2/2.02%7Ebeta3-5+deb9u2/debian/patches/).

So you could have a “stable” 2.00 version if you wanted, but you’d have to live with all the bugs which were discovered afterwards. The important thing to remember really is that a version number (including “alpha”, “beta” etc. monikers) is a name, chosen by the upstream developers; ideally it gives some indication of stability, but in many cases that’s wishful thinking; especially with a project like GRUB, where there’s little hope that the upstream developers can test all the cases which will be encountered in the field.

As with any package in a distribution, you’re trusting the distribution’s developers’ judgment. If they end up shipping what seems like a surprising version number of a given project, there’s often a good reason behind the situation (but it doesn’t hurt to ask!).

Comment: Even easier:  Notice that it is 2.02, not 2.00 as the questioner looks at.  Debian 9 was frozen in January 2017.  GRUB 2.02 was released out of beta in April 2017.

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that, but that begs the question “why didn’t Debian stay on 2.00 instead of jumping to beta versions?” which is what I tried to answer.

Comment: ...but the newer Debian "Buster" installs the stable  GRUB v2.02+dfsg1-20 package.  Why can't "Stretch" do that ?

Comment: No, 2.02+dfsg1-20 is newer that the 2.02 beta versions. 2.02 beta versions are pre-releases of 2.02.