# What would be needed by Debian to ship newer versions of the KDE desktop environment? (Or to add an option for it in Debian stable.)

Tags: debian, kde, upgrade, plasma, stability

The latest version of Debian (10) stable packages version 5.14.5 of KDE Plasma which is [ca. 1.5 years behind the latest release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Plasma_5#Releases). I'd like to use a newer version which only is a few months behind the latest release because I'd like to use new features and bug-fixes.

I don't want to switch to another distro that uses a newer or the latest version of the KDE grahpical workspace environment (and other KDE software): I really like Debian - mainly its thorough dedication to entirely free software, stability, security and large user-base. In the long run I'd prefer if basically all improvements were to be made to Debian itself instead of other distros. Furthermore, I'm asking about Debian stable because I'd like the OS to be as secure and stable as possible and therefore not use or recommend anybody to use Debian testing by-default (stable should probably remain the default variant to use for most) instead. Lastly, I'd like to not create [a "FrankenDebian" as described here](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

I think having a very outdated version of KDE Plasma (along with some other major KDE software) is one of the main disadvantages of Debian which is why I consider this an important issue.

It might also be relevant that the bug-fixes would be consistent with the goal of stability of Debian stable - so a more recent version often means better stability (or at least it could mean that).

[Here somebody used KDE/Plasma 5.18 in Debian](https://www.preining.info/blog/2020/03/kde-plasma-5-18-for-debian/).

---

What would be needed by Debian to package newer version of KDE Plasma?
More testing via more users more quickly and more thoroughly testing the latest version of KDE Plasma in Debian? More devs reviewing code and routine tests of code? Something else?

If it would be better or easier to implement an option for users of Debian stable to use more recent versions of the KDE graphical workspace environment what would be a way to implement such a thing? For example what would be needed by Debian to add a new option to the installer that allows users to choose having a newer version within Debian stable after choosing KDE to be their desktop environment and to allow upgrading to a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

> What would be needed by Debian to package newer version of KDE Plasma?

In the context of a given release, this would require a fundamental change to the stable update rules. Packages are only upgraded in stable if the upgrade fixes a bug qualified with a severity at least “important” ([“a bug which has a major effect on the usability of a package, without rendering it completely unusable to everyone”](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Developer#severities)), and if [the changes in the upgrade are minimal](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html#upload-stable). Upgrading KDE Plasma wholesale doesn’t qualify.

> If it would be better or easier to implement an option for users of Debian stable to use more recent versions of the KDE graphical workspace environment what would be a way to implement such a thing?

Technically, it would be possible to upload a newer version of KDE Plasma to the Debian 11 backports; currently that would be [5.25.4](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/plasma-workspace) since that’s what’s in `testing`. Given the number of packages involved, at least if you want to provide the full [KDE package set](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/meta-kde), that would represent a considerable amount of work.

I don’t think there’s any other simple way to provide an updated desktop environment; Flatpak hardly seems appropriate here, nor does running a separate container for the desktop environment...

Comment: Is there a (another) platform where such a change (an exception to the rule for the desktop environment KDE) could be proposed? Or would things like this be discussed in mailing-lists? Maybe it could be upgraded in a point release if certain criteria is met.    And aren't there more options than backports? For instance, what about adding a new, officially-maintained, repository like "non-free" and "contrib" or like the one Preining set up (I added a link to the question)?

Comment: Another platform, within Debian? Not that I can think of. Things like this would indeed be discussed in the Debian mailing-lists. The point-release criteria are well-defined, see the second link in my answer; KDE Plasma upgrades don’t meet them (except perhaps Plasma point-releases). I don’t think there would be any practical difference between a new “officially-maintained” repository and the existing backports repository; backports are officially-maintained, or at least maintained by official Debian project members.

Comment: As far as Norbert’s repo, it’s a shame he didn’t join the KDE team instead (and there might be good reasons he didn’t) to update Plasma in unstable. His repo is only for testing/unstable so it won’t help you...

Comment: Maybe those criteria could be changed or rather: a specific exception be made for KDE Plasma & all the packages associated with the selected version of it. A new repository instead of changing the version in backports would allow keeping the version in backports that got selected for it and not add any new exceptions/criteria. This way users would have a choice of whether to use the more recent version or the standard backports one. Furthermore, couldn't a new repo dedicated specifically to newer KDE Plasma support allow better integration & prevent a "FrankenDebian" as one would get with bp?

Comment: The criteria don’t need to be changed to allow an updated Plasma in the backports repo, and using the backports repo doesn’t produce a FrankenDebian — backports are [designed to be a safe source of packages for stable](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Some_safer_ways_to_install_software_not_available_in_Debian_Stable). If you want the latest Plasma, get it updated in unstable, wait for it to migrate to testing, then backport it — no exceptions needed, no FrankenDebian, and everyone benefits. I’m pretty sure this is also the approach which requires the least amount of work globally.

Comment: What about a newer version of KDE in the default repo, not backports? This newer version would not be updated often for the reasons you described but it would be a newer main version. Basically why isn't the version in Debian12 KDE Plasma 5.25.4 (or close to it)?

Comment: The version in Debian 12 [*is* 5.25.4](https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/plasma-workspace). (“currently” in the answer was in May 2020.)

Comment: Okay so it seems like this should be solved if Debian upgraded to Debian12 soon. Please comment if one can upgrade to Debian12 before the official upgrade but still get timely security updates etc (which is a problem when switching to testing). Currently it seems like Debian12 would be more stable than Debian11 because of the many KDE bugs in old versions.

Comment: Debian 12 is testing currently, so you’d have exactly the problem you describe with security updates. It will be released sometime next year. If you want security support you’ll have to wait until then…

Comment: Right, I thought maybe it was for example possible to switch to testing for upgrading the kernel and KDE Plasma but _also_ use the Debian 11 repos and install any other software from the Debian 11 repos to get reliable security updates. That's probably not possible so you can only switch to testing or remain at stable. Or [is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107689/233262) [it](https://serverfault.com/q/22414)? (In practice, there's probably too many dependency problems.)

Comment: It’s technically possible, you could add the testing repositories and set things up so that the stable repositories are preferred. However, for the kernel that’s not necessary because testing kernels are regularly made available in stable backports, and as far as KDE is concerned, upgrading to the testing KDE would as you say create too many dependency problems — you’d end up upgrading quite a lot of packages (libraries in particular, notably `libc6`) to their testing versions.